# Nullable getter, but non nullable setter

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Using `c#` version 8.0 introduction of nullable reference types and non-nullable reference types, I can do something like this:

```cs
public class Response
{
    public Response(Exception? ex)
    {
        _ex = ex;
    }

    private Exception? _ex;

    public Exception? Ex
    {
        get => _ex;
        set { _ex = value; }
    }
}
```

I can initialize `_ex` to `null` via the constructor. However, once the instance is created I would like the setter to be unable to set `Ex` value to `null` (by removing the question mark from the type)... something like the code below, which of course, does not compile.

```cs
public class Response
{
    public Response(Exception? ex)
    {
        _ex = ex;
    }

    private Exception? _ex;

    public Exception? Ex
    {
        get => _ex;
    }

    public Exception Ex
    {
        set { _ex = value; }
    }
}
```

One work around of course is to set the `_ex` value with a method, instead of a setter, but I figured to ask anyway.

Comment: What's the purpose of this and why would you need to enforce a non-nullable setter? I'd say it's counter-intuitive for a property to be able to contain null but you can't set it to null.

Comment: Does toggling nullability around the setter with `#nullable enable/disable` annotations work?

Comment: This seems insanely complicated.  Just check for null on setting and if not null, don't allow it to be set.

Comment: @Xerillio Thanks for your reply. The actual use case is more complex  but because of a non disclosure agreement with my client I cannot share the full details. But I completely agree, at first glance, for a simple example like the one I showed in the question, it seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: @abdusco That was a great suggestion, I did not even think of that, but unfortunately it did not work for my needs. At this point I just went with using a method for the setter. Thank u.

Comment: Either, it should be always be nullable or never. As the user of the class might not know if it was constructed with a value or null or if a value was set afterwards, he has to check anyway.  Thus either **(1)** always return an exception object from get or **(2)** allows to set null value. If in a more complex program, you really need to follows some rules, then validate them in the setter.

Comment: The comments here are absurd. There are common use cases for a property that can return null but cannot be set to null, where null means "hasn't been set yet".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the purpose of the `[DisallowNull]` attribute, which "specifies that null is disallowed as an input even if the corresponding type allows it".

Leave the property nullable so that any callers accessing the getter will be properly informed that its value may be null, but attempts to explicitly set it to null will generate the expected warning.

The attribute is added to the property, not the setter:

```cs
[DisallowNull]
public Exception? Ex
{
    get => _ex;
    set => _ex = value;
}
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.disallownullattribute

(Also note that you can use `=>` expression syntax for the `set` as well.)

Comment: Oh cool, this works! Now I am temped to change my code. I already had the implementation using methods. Thank you.

Comment: @Urielzen it really just depends on whether you want to only check at compile time or also enforce it at runtime. Just remember that nullable reference types are not checked at runtime so even though they'll give a warning, they won't actually prevent nulls from being assigned. If that's an issue I would recommend doing both (use `DisallowNull` but also throw exception in the setter if null)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public class Response
{
    public Response(Exception? ex)
    {
        _ex = ex;
    }

    private Exception? _ex;

    public Exception? Ex
    {
        get => _ex;
        set { 
            if ( _ex!=null && value==null ) throw exeption; // or just ignore maybe
           else  _ex = value; 
            }
    }
}
```

if Exeption is  a reference type , and C# version allows reference types be null too, this is a right code also

```
public class Response
{
    public Response(Exception ex)
    {
        _ex = ex;
    }

    private Exception _ex;

    public Exception Ex
    {
        get => _ex;
        set { 
            if ( _ex!=null && value==null ) throw exeption; // or just ignore maybe
           else  _ex = value; 
            }
    }
}
```

the most important part of this code doesn't allow to set null if it is not null already. @golakwer code doesn't have this part:

```
if ( _ex!=null && value==null ) throw exeption; // or just ignore maybe
           else  _ex = value;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you add an **!** after a variable that is nullable the compiler allows you to assign a non-nullable variable to a nullable variable.

So that **Ex** property can be non-nullable but in the constructor a nullable value can be assigned.

```
public class Response
{
    public Response(Exception? ex)
    {
        _ex = ex!;
    }

    private Exception _ex;

    public Exception Ex
    {
        get => _ex;
        set { _ex = value; }
    }
}
```

[Further](https://www.automatetheplanet.com/embracing-non-nullable-reference-types/) reading.

Comment: But now the consumer of `Response.Ex` believes it'll never be null and run into unexpected null-ref issues.

Comment: @Xerillio sure but thats outside the scope of the question...

Comment: I would argue otherwise. Why else make use of nullable reference types if not to help the programmer make safe code?

Comment: @Xerillio actually this nullable check is compile time only, there is no guarantee that `Response.Ex` will never be nullable whether its marked as nullable or not. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references

Comment: Yes, but I think your answer is missing an explanation for why it's a good solution make the property non-nullable while still assigning null to it. In my mind this is counterproductive and is more likely to cause issues down the line.

Comment: @Xerillio true that its possible that it will be counterproduction and even likely but I cant determine that without more info. I could come up with a contrived example where something like this would be useful... and I also could come up with a contrived example where something that seems completely reasonable would be detrimental. IMO it depends on the context, and no context is given except "The actual use case is more complex but because of a non disclosure agreement with my client I cannot share the full details". So lets give Urielzen the benefit of the doubt...

Comment: @golakwer I would say that you should never suggest a  discutable practice as an answer without proper explanation.

Comment: "sure but thats outside the scope of the question... " The question *specifically* asks for a nullable getter.  This just doesn't answer the question at all, in addition to being a truly awful idea.

Comment: @Servy "The question specifically asks for a nullable getter." where do you see that?

Comment: The title, the fact that they asked to change *the setter* rather than the whole property, to be non-nullable, the fact that they showed the code that they wanted as having a non-nullable setter and a nullable getter, them mentioning the need to use a method to have the types differ, basically the whole question.  What about the question makes you think they wanted to just change the type of the property and nothing more than that?

Comment: @Servy fair enough.